# Loading and converting json file in R

Tags: json, r, matrix, dataframe

I have .json file which I need to load in R and perform further operations with it after converting it into a data-frame. Initials of my json file looks like this:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"57a30ce268fd0809ec4d194f"},"session":{"start_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470183490481"},"session_id":"def5faa9-20160803-001810481"},"metrics":{},"arrival_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470183523054"},"event_type":"OfferViewed","event_timestamp":{"$numberLong":"1470183505399"},"event_version":"3.0","application":{"package_name":"com.think.vito","title":"Vito","version_code":"5","app_id":"7ffa58dab3c646cea642e961ff8a8070","cognito_identity_pool_id":"us-east-1:4d9cf803-0487-44ec-be27-1e160d15df74","version_name":"2.0.0.0","sdk":{"version":"2.2.2","name":"aws-sdk-android"}},"client":{"cognito_id":"us-east-1:2e26918b-f7b1-471e-9df4-b931509f7d37","client_id":"ee0b61b0-85cf-4b2f-960e-e2aedef5faa9"},"device":{"locale":{"country":"US","code":"en_US","language":"en"},"platform":{"version":"5.1.1","name":"ANDROID"},"make":"YU","model":"AO5510"},"attributes":{"Category":"120000","CustomerID":"4078","OfferID":"45436"}}
```

Above sample is just one id, session, metrics and there are many like that.

I tried converting it using rjson library in R as follows. events_jason is the filename:

```
library(rjson)
result <- fromJSON(file = "events_json.json")
print(result)



 $`_id`
$`_id`$`$oid`
[1] "57a30ce268fd0809ec4d194f"


$session
$session$start_timestamp
$session$start_timestamp$`$numberLong`
[1] "1470183490481"


$session$session_id
[1] "def5faa9-20160803-001810481"


$metrics
list()

$arrival_timestamp
$arrival_timestamp$`$numberLong`
[1] "1470183523054"


$event_type
[1] "OfferViewed"

$event_timestamp
$event_timestamp$`$numberLong`
[1] "1470183505399"


$event_version
[1] "3.0"

$application
$application$package_name
[1] "com.think.vito"

$application$title
[1] "Vito"

$application$version_code
[1] "5"

$application$app_id
[1] "7ffa58dab3c646cea642e961ff8a8070"

$application$cognito_identity_pool_id
[1] "us-east-1:4d9cf803-0487-44ec-be27-1e160d15df74"

$application$version_name
[1] "2.0.0.0"

$application$sdk
$application$sdk$version
[1] "2.2.2"

$application$sdk$name
[1] "aws-sdk-android"



$client
$client$cognito_id
[1] "us-east-1:2e26918b-f7b1-471e-9df4-b931509f7d37"

$client$client_id
[1] "ee0b61b0-85cf-4b2f-960e-e2aedef5faa9"


$device
$device$locale
$device$locale$country
[1] "US"

$device$locale$code
[1] "en_US"

$device$locale$language
[1] "en"


$device$platform
$device$platform$version
[1] "5.1.1"

$device$platform$name
[1] "ANDROID"


$device$make
[1] "YU"

$device$model
[1] "AO5510"


$attributes
$attributes$Category
[1] "120000"

$attributes$CustomerID
[1] "4078"

$attributes$OfferID
[1] "45436"
```

But it's just showing/reading the first row as I mentioned above. There are other more ids, session, metrics,event_type,etc which it is not showing.

Please help how can i read my whole json file so that i can see other rows as well and covert it into a proper data frame.

**UPDATE:**

I have found the solution. Using ndjson package I am getting desired data frame.

```
library(ndjson)
df<-ndjson::stream_in('events_data.json')
```

Comment: You should give us at least a couple of json rows/records. As of this we can't reproduce your error, so we can't even begin to help you

Comment: Your JSON does not validate, please provide a reproducible data set so that we can do something

Comment: @GGamba  - I have provided the snapshopt. Please check!

Comment: We can't do anything with a cropped image, pls provide some copy-able input

Comment: @GGamba
Okay. Here it is. Link - https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzOdqQyzNCvWMW1QSlhFR05lSnM

Comment: Cool. I was _just_ abt to suggest: `ndjson::stream_in("events_data.json")`

Answer (score 0):

Your file is not a single json object, but rather a list of json obejcts, one for each line. You have to read each line and convert each one from json.
One way to do that is:

```
d <- lapply(strsplit(readLines("events_data2.json"),"\n"), fromJSON)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It's an ndjson file. `jsonlite::stream_in()` or `ndjson::stream_in()` are _far_ more appropriate solutions